# How to change Frame.size using CABasicAnimation

Tags: cocoa-touch, caanimation

Hi i have change the frame size using CABasicAnimation i used below code

```
CABasicAnimation *newanim; 
newanim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds.size"];

newanim.duration=3.0;
newanim.fromValue=[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(0,0)];
newanim.toValue=[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(self.backgroundImageView.bounds.size.width, self.foregroundImageView.bounds.size.height)];

newanim.fillMode=kCAFillModeForwards;
newanim.autoreverses = YES;
newanim.repeatCount = 1;
newanim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
[self.view.layer addAnimation:newanim forKey:@"changeSize"];
```

But the animation starts for origin and moves both side(like animation starts from center).

i tried by changing
    newanim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"frame.size"];

it not work at all.

Answer (score 12):

Apple has an answer for that: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1620/_index.html

But personally I don't think this is the best way, CATransform3DMakeScale seems better:

```
CABasicAnimation *transformAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
transformAnimation.duration=3.0;
transformAnimation.toValue=[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY, scaleFactorZ)];
transformAnimation.removedOnCompletion = FALSE;

[layer addAnimation:transformAnimation forKey:@"transform"];
```

Answer (score 3):

To scale the frame of a layer in **Swift 5** you can use:

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.y")
animation.toValue = 0.1
animation.duration = 1.5
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.init(name: .easeInEaseOut)
layer.add(animation, forKey: "animation_scale_y")
```

While `transfrom.scale.y` scales the height, `transfrom.scale.x` scales the width and `transfrom.scale.z` the depth of the layer.

To transform all scale parameters in one animation you can use

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
animation.toValue = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1, 0.1, 1)
animation.duration = 1.5
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.init(name: .easeInEaseOut)
layer.add(animation, forKey: "animation_scale")
```